# Sending a common 'text' with all Prometheus alert emails

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, monitoring, prometheus-alertmanager

I have installed one monitoring setup in Kubernetes. I have used Promethuese, and for alerting I have configured alert manager. Everything is working fine.

I have one requirement to send a common text, say for eg:- a wiki URL with all the alert emails. I can do it by editing all the alert blocks, but is there a way to add just this line in a commonplace so that it will be picked up whenever alert manager sends an email?

```
alertmanagerFiles:
  alertmanager.yml:
    global:
      resolve_timeout: 5m
      smtp_smarthost: 'xxxxx:portnumber'
      smtp_from: 'email@domain.com'
      smtp_auth_username: 'xxxx'
      smtp_auth_password: 'xxxxx'
      smtp_require_tls: false
    route:
      group_by: ['alertname', 'cluster', 'service']
      group_wait: 30s
      group_interval: 5m
      repeat_interval: 30m
      receiver: ops
    inhibit_rules:
    - source_match:
        severity: 'critical'
      target_match:
        severity: 'warning'
      equal: ['alertname', 'cluster', 'service']
    receivers:
      - name: 'ops'
        email_configs:
        - to: 'xxxxx'
          send_resolved: true
        - to: 'xxxxx'
          send_resolved: true
```

This is the alert manager config

Comment: Sounds like you'd best create a [Custom Alertmanager Template](https://prometheus.io/blog/2016/03/03/custom-alertmanager-templates/) for HTML mails…

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use? It is important to reproduce your situation.